# How to update axvspan when item is selected from radio button

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, widget

I have a chart where the user can click on a radio button and part of the chart is highlighted using an axvspan object. This works great for the first selection but each additional selection will just plot another axvspan object instead of updating the existing one.

This is a simplified version of what I have created:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
ax.plot(y)
ax.axis([0,10,0,10])

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

rax = plt.axes([.01, 0.55, 0.15, 0.3], aspect='equal',frameon=False )
radio = RadioButtons(rax, y)
for circle in radio.circles:
    circle.set_radius(0.02)
def update(label):
    num = int(label)
    ax.axvspan(num, num+1, alpha=0.3, color='xkcd:crimson')
    plt.draw()

radio.on_clicked(update)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the existing `axvspan` and use its `remove()` method on each call to `update()`:

```
spans = []

def update(label):
    num = int(label)
    if len(spans):
        for span in spans:
            try:
                span.remove()
            except ValueError:
                continue
    spans.append(ax.axvspan(num, num+1, alpha=0.3, color='xkcd:crimson'))
    plt.draw()

radio.on_clicked(update)
plt.show()
```